# How to start up a program as administrator in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

One of the program I add in the OS startup list (press windows key > all programs > startup) requires administrator privilege. How can I configure it to run as administrator?

Comment: Are you an administrator on the machine, and just worried it will not run as an administrator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UAC will not allow a program to run as administrator on startup unless it is Code Signed.  You would need to turn off UAC and also be running as an administrator.  This will reduce your system's security however.

Here is a tweak that worked in Vista, should work in Windows 7, although I have not tested it yet.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/616

Answer (score -1):

Be an administrator. The purpose of having different privilege levels is to prevent unauthorized persons from running certain programs. If the administrator has blocked a program, it cannot be run. If it requires admin privileges, then an admin can run it.

Answer (score -1):

To make it more clear, log in as an administrator, asign admin privileges to your personal account, log out and then login with your personal account and you should be able to run the program.

Comment: This won't work as with Windows Vista/7, you do not run as Administrator, even if your account is part of the Administrators group.  UAC is required to escalate the user's privileges and it is only for that process.